# python fit the Lennard-Jones pair function

Tags: python, function, curve-fitting

I have a binary system (AB), and calculated the total energies of 10 structures. Then, I want to use python to fit energies using the Lennard-Jones (LJ) pair function and get their corresponding parameters (epsilon and sigma). The LJ function is:

```
U(r)=4*epsilon [(sigma/r)^12 + (sigma/r)^6],
```

where r is the interatomic distance. For the AB binary system, it includes three type interactions: A-A, A-B and B-B, and thus six fitting parameters epsilon(A-A), sigma(A-A), epsilon(A-B), sigma(A-B), epsilon(B-B) and sigma(B-B) are required. In the other words, there are three parts [U(A-A), U(A-B) and U(B-B)] in the total U function. The input r variable is a list like this:

```
r=[[[A,A],2.0], [[A,A],3.0],...,[[A,B],2.0], [[A,B],3.0],...,[[B,B],2.0],[[B,B],3.0] ...]
```

Thus, I need to group A-A, A-B, and B-B interatomic distances to corresponding function (U(A-A), U(A-B), and U(B-B)). But, I don't know to correctly write the function and calling line:

```
def func(r,energy):
  for i in range(len(r)):
    if r[i][0]==[A,A]:
      U0=U(A-A)
    elif: r[i][0]=[A,B]:
      U0=U(A-B)
    else: U0=U(B-B)
    U=U+U0
  return U

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, r, energy)
```

On the other hand, I also want to fit the forces (the first derivative of the potential) at the same time? How to minimize the energy and force fitting errors simultaneously, minimize(energy, force), to get the best fitting parameters (epsilon, sigma) for both energy and forces? Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the number in `r`, it is the energy of the pair or their distance?

Comment: r is actually a list: r[0] indicates [A,A] or [A,B], or [B,B] and r[1] the distance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you want to have is a list of "atomic pairs", each with 3 values: (type1, type2, distance**6), where type1 and type2 each have one of two values 'a' or 'b'.  You *could* start with a list of "atomic coordinates", (type, x, y, z), but you could then reduce that list to the list of "atomic pairs".

Then, you want 6 variable: epsAA, epsAB, epsBB, sigAA, sigAB, sigBB.

Your function should take as input an array with the values for these 6 variables and the pairs data, and return an array of the energies (that is, the energy for each pair), perhaps like:

```
import numpy as np
def objective(params, pairsdata):
    epsAA, epsAB, epsBB, sigAA, sigAB, sigBB = params
    u = np.zeros(len(pairsdata))
    for i, pairs in enumerate(pairsdata):
        t1, t2, r6 = pairsdata
        eps, sig6 = epsAB, sigAB # default to different types
        if t1 == t2: 
            eps, sig6 = epsAA, sigAA
            if t1 == 'b':
                eps, sig6 = epsBB, sigBB
        arg = sig6/r6
        u[i] = 4 * eps * arg * (arg + 1) 
    return u
```

Then, you could use that with `scipy.optimize.leastsq()`.

I think you probably want to store the `r**6` (and `sigma**6`), and square that, not actually use the sixth and twelfth power each time (what were these Lennard and Jones people thinking? that computers had infinite precision? ;) ).

It would be worth thinking about how to avoid for loop, but you didn't say you wanted it to be fast, just correct ;).

If you want to include some measure of force, I think you'd need to calculate that by a finite difference method, and then use both U and dU/dr  by *concatenating* the array of energies and an array of forces (that is return an array with twice as many values as pairs).

Answer (score 0):

Thank Newvillle's answer. For a simpler case, I write a short python program. It might clarify my question.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize 


def func(p,x,ydata):
  f=4*p[0]*( (p[1]/x)**12 - (p[1]/x)**6 )
  return f

dis=[[3.45454545455,3.63636363636,4.0],[3.54545454545,4.18181818182,5.0],[3.81818181818,4.45454545455,4.90909090909], [3.72727272727,4.36363636364,5.36363636364],[3.90909090909,5.27272727273,6.0]]

ene=[-1.3, -1.4, -2.0, -2.2, -1.3]
xdata=np.array(dis)
ydata=np.array(ene)

p0=[0.5,3.0]
print scipy.optimize.leastsq(func, p0, args=(xdata,ydata))
```

Comment: Was the previous answer helpful or not?   (you should accept the answer if so, or upvote it)  Here, it *looks* like 'dis' has three values -- what do these represent?  There is one distance between atomic pairs: The L-J potential is a one dimensional problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your response is helpful, but doesn't fix my problem. It seem my question is not clear. In the simple python program (only considering A-A), 'dis' represent the group of distances between any two atoms for each configure, and 'ene' is the corresponding energy of each configuration: f(3.45)+f(3.63)+f(4.0)=-1.3; f(3.54)+f(4.18)+f(5.0)=-1.4; f(3.81)+f(4.45)+f(4.90)=-2.0 ... I am trying to use the five formulas to fit the two parameters (p[0] and p[1]). Thanks

Comment: Distance `r` is a scalar value, your `dis` is an list with 5 elements (corresponding to `ene`), but each entry has 3 values, not 1.  Are those 3 different distances?  Do you mean to loop over those?  Or perhaps those are /not/ distance but differences in (x,y,z), in which case you need to compute the distance.   The returned array should really be a 1-D array with 5 elements (for the 5 values of `ene`).   Also: try printing out intermediate results to see what the calculation is doing.

Comment: Yes, they are 3 different distances and I need to loop over them to get one  ene[i], e.g. f(3.45)+f(3.63)+f(4.0)=-1.3. It means that the total energy of a system is -1.3eV and each distance (3.45, 3.63 and 4.0) contributes part of the total energy. thanks.

Comment: your code is not looping over the elements of `x` but using numpy broadcasting.  Again, you may want to call `func` once and look at the result.  `f` will have a shape of (5, 3).  You'll need to flatten that: the objective should return a 1d array.